# data type time in sql server shows error when I try to insert hours

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table called service order which has columns called "From" and "To". The data type for those columns is `time(2)`.

When I try to insert a value into that column in sql server management studio, it show an error message says `SqlDbType.Time overflow. value '8.00:00:00' is out of range`.

Why is not allowing me to insert?

what data type I should use for a field that holds time only?

Comment: Are you sure it's `'8.00:00:00'` and not `'8:00:00:00'`?

Comment: `8` translates to 8 days.  If you want 8 hours, try `'08:00:00.000'` or `DATEADD(hour, 8, 0)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I only type number 8 and the sql management studio automatically fills in the rest as '8.00:00:00'. but your format works, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8.00:00:00` isn't a number of hours - I'd have expected you to use `08:00:00` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Time format of `HH:mm:ss` instead.

[Date and Time Data in SQL Server 2008 (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx)

Comment: I only type number 8 and the sql management studio automatically fills in the rest as '8.00:00:00', and when I try to insert it, it shows error.

Comment: Stop pasting into the Open Table grid. Write an insert statement then you can prevent the buggy designers from misinterpreting what you meant.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for your good advise. I'll try using it.